# Problema para ejecutar proyecto de Spring Boot

Tags: java, netbeans, tomcat

Quiero hacer una consulta sobre Spring Boot. Ya generé el proyecto desde Initializr y lo descomprimí, pero abro el proyecto con Netbeans y cuando lo quiero correr estoy teniendo el siguiente error:

> Error: Could not find or load main class ${exec.mainClass}
> Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: ${exec.mainClass}
> Command execution failed.
> Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:3.0.0:exec (default-cli) on project SpringBoot

El código de la app es:

```
    package com.ejemplo.SpringBoot;

    import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
    import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

    @SpringBootApplication
    public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

   }
```

Y el pom.xml es:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org
    /2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org
    /xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.2</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.ejemplo</groupId>
    <artifactId>SpringBoot</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>SpringBoot</name>
    <description>Mi primer proyecto con Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    </project>
```

¿A qué se debe? ¿Alguien sabe?

Comment: No creo que en el pom pueda haber errores, ya que eso lo generó el Spring Initializr. Siempre es necesario verificar todos los plugins instalados en tu proyecto, para eso, en la consola ejecuta `mvn clean install`, me avisas como te va.

Comment: Ya lo solucioné! Por alguna razón, Initializr no me había generado la siguiente línea:

`<start-class>com.ejemplo.SpringBoot.Application</start-class>`

Que tenía que ponerla dentro de properties y debajo de java version. La puse y arrancó la aplicación sin problemas. Gracias!